# Android: org.JSONException "String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

Tags: php, android, json

Hello I'm new to Android especially JSon. I'm trying to connect my android application with my php file connected to WAMP.
But I'm getting "String cannot be converted to JSONObject.
Here's my php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['check'])){

$name = $_POST['txtuser'];
$pass = $_POST['txtpass'];

$sql = "Select * from tbluser where username = '".$name."' and password = '".$pass."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$flag['code'] = 0;

if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){

$flag['code'] = 1;
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Hello");</script>';
json_encode($flag);

}
```

and here's my Android code:

```
public void select()
{
ArrayList<NameValuePair> userpass = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

String x = txtname.getText().toString();
String y = txtpass.getText().toString();

userpass.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", x));
userpass.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass",y));

try
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.254.100/adphptest/index.php");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(userpass));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}     

try
{

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
    (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    json = sb.toString();
Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
}     

try
{
    JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(json);


    code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

    if(code==1)
    {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "User verified!",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid!",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the JSON Reponse.

Comment: you mean this: {"code":1}

Comment: Yeah, so is this the json response when evr the request got posted?

Comment: Log the response after json = sb.toString(); , like Log.d("X",json), and copy paste it here, i need the real response, not the expected one.

Comment: uhm yes, but only if num_rows condition is met.

Comment: it gives me an html code saying I dont have permission to access adphptest/index.php

Comment: I think the problem rising when ever the user is Invalid, because in that case you are not echoing anything. You should echo the result, no matter valid or invalid user , like `{"status":"invalid"}` if invalid user and if valid show `{"status":"valid"}` . i mean not exactly like this. you have to output the result in every case.

Comment: but it also happens when I typed in the correct user. I'm thinking that there might be something wrong with my httppost url. my php file is under C:/wamp/www ...

Comment: have you set the internet  permission in your manifest ?

Comment: yes i have already set it.

Comment: Can you post the entire error ? i mean the html error that you said about the Permission.

Comment: <h1>Forbidden</h1><p>You don't have permission to access /adphptest/index.php</p>

Comment: I've posted one answer,  check it out.

Comment: still giving me I don't have permission to access... Do I have to put 127.0.01/adphptest/index.php?

Comment: try it out, i never used localhost to network test.

Comment: Connection is refused.

Comment: Ken i just updated the answer, please take a look,  the from to section got some modification.

Comment: Now I can access it but, still getting string cannot be converted.

Comment: Can you post what the logcat says ?

Comment: JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Now the problem is with your JSON Format and Parsing. Log the JSON Response after inputstream close() . Log.d("X",sb.toString()); and show me that what logcat says .

Comment: have you set the content type using `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Answer (score 0):

> Go to c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf and change this

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: You have to set the content-type as json in your php file, put this on the first line `header('Content-Type: application/json');` . and try again.

Comment: now I'm getting I don't have permission again. Actually I tried uploading it online, but when I click the btnli [android] it didn't respond.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've missed something obvious the problem is that before outputting the json object your php file is echoing a non json string with this line

`echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Hello");</script>';`

That is the first thing your Android json parsing code sees hence the failure.

Comment: Ohh, does it cause a problem ?? have you ever been faced something like this ?

Comment: Yes. It's not valid JSON and so cannot be parsed as such. Try commenting out that line, see what happens.

Comment: @Ken, comment the line as Ivan said.

Comment: tried removing the script, but still no luck... still getting JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: there's a problem with you php code. What does it look like when you open it in a browser?

Comment: well aside from the php file being simple, it is working fine as far as I know.

Comment: You most likely have your php code inside a html file. Strip out everything except the php code and you should be good.